# Change text of the labels in DialogViewController already loaded monotouch.dialog

Tags: xamarin.ios, monotouch.dialog

Hello to all :) I want to change the text on the labels of my monotouch application (localization feature), I usually do this job in the ViewWillAppear method. But i was wondering how i could do this in the cleanest way in monotouch.dialog. (I used to assign the text to the elements and send all the root structure to the constructor of the DialogViewController). Thanks for your answers.

Comment: Could you clarify your question ? It's not clear if you want to update existing `Element` inside a `DialogViewController` at runtime (e.g. switch from English to French) **or** if you're looking for suggestions about localizing an application that depends on MonoTouch.Dialog (decide to display French instead of English before displaying the UI).

Comment: Hello, is about suggestions about localizing (which implies initially change the text on the elements, maybe updating all the root). How can I accomplish this? Is a good option to inherit from DialogViewController and override the ViewWillAppear?